# Skipped Loading Symbols Statement in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wpf, arcgis, arcgis-runtime-net

Hi i am trying to import my custom made 3d symbol onto the scene , it was working fine a week ago but now it keeps giving me this statement and doesn't render any symbols on my scene

*'DisplayAScene.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.3\System.Net.Primitives.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DisplayAScene.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.3\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
'DisplayAScene.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\6.0.3\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll'. Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just*

can any one tell me why this is happening?

Comment: That's a perfectly normal thing to see in your output window. This isn't the reason your model symbol is not loading. It is not referring to "3d symbols" but the debug symbols for your DLLs (so a different kind of symbol)